AST extraction changing output values for python source code
I have a RL source code, in which I am looking to extract different metrics, one such is the parameters, which are always of the following form:
total_timesteps: int = int(25e6)
env_id: str = "pilot"
buffer_size: int = int(1e6)
learning_rate: float = 5e-4
anneal_lr: bool = False
target_kl: float = None
I wish to extract three things from this, the parameter, data type and value. The output would be something like this:



Parameter
Data Type
Value




total_timesteps
int
int(25e6)


env_id
str
pilot


learning_rate
float
5e-4


anneal_lr
bool
False


target_kl
float
None


buffer_size
int
int(1e6)



This is what I did till now,
import sys
from tabulate import tabulate

def extract_parameters_with_values_from_file(file_path: str) -> dict:
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        source_code = file.read()

    parameter_values = {}

    tree = ast.parse(source_code)
    for node in ast.walk(tree):
        if isinstance(node, ast.AnnAssign):
            parameter_name = node.target.id
            if isinstance(node.annotation, ast.Name):
                data_type = node.annotation.id
            else:
                data_type = str(ast.dump(node.annotation))
            if isinstance(node.value, ast.Constant):
                parameter_value = node.value.value
            elif isinstance(node.value, ast.NameConstant):
                parameter_value = node.value.value
            else:
                parameter_value = ast.dump(node.value)
            parameter_values[parameter_name] = (data_type, parameter_value)

    return parameter_values

def read_parameters_from_txt(file_path: str) -> list:
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        parameters = file.read().splitlines()
    return parameters

def extract_parameters_with_values(parameter_names: list, python_file_path: str) -> list:
    parameter_values = extract_parameters_with_values_from_file(python_file_path)
    extracted_parameters = []

    for parameter_name in parameter_names:
        if parameter_name in parameter_values:
            data_type, value = parameter_values[parameter_name]
            extracted_parameters.append([parameter_name, data_type, value])

    return extracted_parameters

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        sys.exit(1)

    parameter_txt_path = sys.argv[1]
    python_file_path = sys.argv[2]

    parameter_names = read_parameters_from_txt(parameter_txt_path)
    extracted_parameters = extract_parameters_with_values(parameter_names, python_file_path)

    if not extracted_parameters:
        print("No parameters found in the source code")
    else:
        print(tabulate(extracted_parameters, headers=['Parameter', 'Data Type', 'Value'], tablefmt="github"))


This extracts them in the given output format, however changes the values of int and float, and for some of the parameters, I am getting a completely different output under the Value column. Any suggestions/help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Could you give a concrete example of the incorrect results you're seeing?

@jasonharper This is the source code on which I am performing the extraction: https://github.com/vwxyzjn/cleanrl/blob/master/cleanrl/td3_continuous_action.py
So, when I try to run my current code on it, for buffer_size , the output under valuecolumn should be int(1e6), however I get Call(func=Name(id='int', ctx=Load()), args=[Constant(value=1000000.0)], keywords=[]), which is nowhere mentioned in the code

That AST structure is exactly how int(1e6) is represented.  (AST can't distinguish between 1e6 and 1000000.0, they're the same number.)
